# CSS Change the Arrows in Fullpage.js to custom images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpageJS https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/ to make my website. I wanted to change the arrows to display custom images instead. I found this question asked earlier here [CSS: change arrows on fullpage JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785914/css-change-arrows-on-fullpage-js) and I attempted to overwrite the jquery.fullPage.css with my own arrows.css style and didn't get the images to display. I'm relatively new to coding so I'm not really sure of the best way to overwrite the original css.

The original css for the arrows:

```
.fp-controlArrow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: -38px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    left: 15px;
    width: 0;
    border-width: 38.5px 34px 38.5px 0;
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    right: 15px;
    border-width: 38.5px 0 38.5px 34px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}
```

My code for the arrows.css style:

```
.fp-controlArrow {
    position: absolute;
    width:146px !important;
    height:286px !important;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 50%;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    background-image: url(images/leftnavbutton.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left: 0px;
    height:286px;
    width: 146px;
    z-index: 10; 
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    background-image: url(images/rightnavbutton.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    right: 0px;
    height:286px;
    width:146px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code like this instead:

```
.fp-controlArrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 128px; /* This can be added here so you don't have to set a width and height 2 times for each arrow, this will create one width for both arrows */
    height: 128px; /* This does the same as above */
    margin-top:-64px; /* This value must always be half of the height - This does the same as above */
    z-index: 4;
    top: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    left:0;
    background: url(images/rightnavbutton.png) no-repeat;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    right:0;
    background: url(images/rightnavbutton.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Definitely makes the code tidier, but my images are still not showing up in place of the original arrows. Is there a better way to override the css?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're not pointing the `background` URL to the right URL Path. I've tested this on Jsfiddle and it is working just fine. I couldn't paste the Jsfiddle file here because there's is a problem in saving all of the FullpageJS code on Jsfiddle. It doesn't accept saving it I don't know why

Comment: Here. Try to replace this `background: url(images/rightnavbutton.png) no-repeat;` with this `background: url(http://www.mricons.com/store/png/110949_27865_128_play_right%20arrow_icon.png) no-repeat;` and you'll see the image appearing. This was the image I was using when I tested it

Comment: Yes that was the problem, fixed the path and it works. Thanks a lot for the help!